# Download multiple mp3's from a website

Tags: mp3

I would like to write a program or script that will go through a website and download all MP3's. So for example, I would go to a website that has MP3's available for download. I would then run a script or start a program that would comb through the website downloading all or specified MP3's.

I don't know where to start or if an application already exists. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download any resource from an HTTP protocol or from a website first, you have to know the url. To get the url you better have access to the code source and use a regex that start with http:// or https:// and end with .mp3. And/or follow any link in the source code and check if the mime type is audio/mp3.

Note: you can't go on a website and download any resource illegally. You have to respect the copyright.